# Sync NSUserDefaults between iOS simulators

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, ios8, xcode6

Is it possible to keep all the simulators in sync with the same NSUserDefaults?  Each simulator seems to have it saved to a different place.  I'm setting up my app for screenshots and it's tedious to have to recreate everything for each simulator (iPhone 4s, iPhone 5s, iPhone 6, iPhone 6 Plus).

Comment: Did you try copying the NSUserDefaults plist file from one simulator to the other?

Answer (score 1):

CoreSimulator is specifically designed to segregate this data.  As you may be aware, the fact that older simulators shared data between all devices on the same version resulted in many problems.  The new system (CoreSimulator) allows you to manage many distinct simulated devices, each with its own data directory.

If you really want to do this, you can link all the devices' data directories to the same place (ie, one real and the others as symlinks).  See ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/*/data

Answer (score 0):

"A defaults database is created automatically for each user."

But you can use [MKiCloudSync](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKiCloudSync) for that. Here's [tutorial](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/ios-code-mkicloudsync-sync-your-nsuserdefaults-to-icloud-with-a-single-line-of-code/) of implementation.